# php и MVC

Tags: php, mvc

Есть у меня не большая, так скажем задача написать для себя не большой веб-ресурс. Раньше писалось у меня спокойно и хорошо, но все чаще стало на езжать на меня аббревиатура MVC. Правда начать с чего я не знаю, может кто не много прояснит "this situation", может быть даст пару ссылок.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://wikipedia.ru/MVC
MVC - это **паттерн** проектирования. Т.е. некий готовый шаблон, говорящий о том, как вещи должны быть организованы.
Но перед тем как бросаться на паттерны советую Вам убедиться что с ООП у вас все в порядке, т.к. паттерны сами по-себе реализованы (по большей части) на классах и их взаимодействии между собой.  
MVC говорит Вам, что у вас есть, грубо говоря (но не обязательно) три класса - один Модель (отвечает за данные и работу с ними), другой называется Вид (View, отвечает за все внешнее представление вашего приложение), и третий - Controller, или Логика (он же логика вавшего приложения).
Вообще по этой теме написано полно книг, так что читайте, изучайте.

Comment: Ну это я слышал, ранее приходилось только редактировать сайта написанные с применением MVC. Что такое ООП, ну тоже работал. Вот в том и проблема что книг, много.

Comment: берите любую и читайте вдумчиво от корки до корки.

Comment: А что по поводу фреймворков

Comment: сначала разберись хорошо с ООП, потом пойми смысл MVC, ну а дальше фреймворки, но опять же фреймворки бывают разные, и следуя из этого бывают разные паттерны проектирования

Comment: @Алексей Скляр

     сначала разберись хорошо с ООП

Это опять про:

     Object-oriented programming generates a lot of what looks like work. Back in the days of fanfold, there was a type of programmer who would only put five or ten lines of code on a page, preceded by twenty lines of elaborately formatted comments. Object-oriented programming is like crack for these people: it lets you incorporate all this scaffolding right into your source code. Something that a Lisp hacker might handle by pushing a symbol onto a list becomes a whole file of classes and methods.

Answer (score 1):

Если честно, то я лично не знаком с таким шаблоном программирования, однако частично представляю его. Вам не обязательно его применять, ведь это всего лишь "некий совет", дабы всё привести к единому виду в вашей системе, это поможет вам следовать некому стандарту, основанному вами же самим. Как правило **MVC** отделяет **HTML** код от **PHP**, грубо говоря и мягко выражаясь. Я пишу свою CMS систему под собственные нужды и нужды друзей, в ней нет ни классов, ни **MVC**, однако присутствует "классность", к примеру : у системы есть : **расширения и инструменты**, расширения именуются только своим названием, а **инструменты** - **владелец_tools_название_инструмента**. Очень важно знать принципы и способы, но не обязательно ими пользоваться.

Comment: Не обязательно конечно,но если придумать свой вариант который на порядок ниже качеством то стоит и нужно пользоваться уже давно известными и популярными паттернами,Стоит ли заморачиваться с шаблонами проектирования? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/510342/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan больно поздно вы комментируете такой древний ответ. На данный момент я отказался от написания CMS и написал framework(ну почти, нужна финальная перепись). Классы использую(singleton), MVC не использую.