# Стоит ли заморачиваться с шаблонами проектирования?

Tags: php, ооп, шаблоны-проектирования, design

На данный момент изучаю шаблоны проектирования и пробую применять их на практике, но из-за небольшого опыта работы с ними и отсутствия менторства в этом деле прошу у вас помощи.

Есть, например, задача - сделать стрипт для связи с людьми.

Подробней:
Мы говорим что хотим связаться с пользователем определенным способом, задаем вспомогательную информацию для объекта, далее говорим отправить. В идеале вижу использование скрипта в виде с использованием фабрики и стратегии:

```
$object = Communication::GetDriver('sms');
$object->setMsg($text);
$object->setTelephone($phone);
$object->send();
```

Но может потребоваться отправить совершенно другим способом, например, в соцсеть.

```
$object = Communication::GetDriver('socialNetwork');
$object->setMsg($text);
$object->setIdUser($id);
$object->send();
```

Вот и вопрос, как лучше поступить? Стоит ли заморачиваться с шаблонами? Может быть, следует сделать все это отдельными классами? Это будет оправдано? При этом желательно ловить ошибки и вести лог происходящего.

А если использовать шаблоны то как объединить классы? Может быть, есть методы, как сделать лучше?

Comment: можно такого шаблонами проектирования нагородить, что потом не разобрать будет. Поэтому я обычно пишу вначале минимально, что бы оно завелось. Но оставляю "заначки". И в процессе написания рабочего прототипа, обычно меняется несколько концепций. Умение угадать, какие правильно паттерны и где применить в конкретной задаче - это и отличает хорошего программиста от обычного.

Comment: @KoVadim я согласен. Но это приходит с опытом. Тут я бы как раз использовал их и надеюсь на советы по применению потому что написать то я могу сам. Но нужно 3-е мнение как может кто-то другой сделает. Может его логика лучше или он знает то чего я не знаю. Век живи век учись) Буду очень благодарен если приведете пример как бы вы сделали в расчете на то что  способы отправки будут обновляться и добавляться.

Comment: при первом взгляде  я бы сделал setIdUser и setTelephone одним методом и назвал бы его как то setSenderInfo и передавал ему строку. А каждый "драйвер" уже расшифровывал эту строку и правильно интерпретировал.

Но можно сделать отдельный класс - DriverSetting и функцию, которая его наполнит. Тогда setSender будет получать на вход один с наследников этого класса.

Comment: абстрактный класс реализующий формирование сообщения. два класса sms и socialNetwork находящийся в пространстве имен классов драйверов. getDriver метод определяет какой класс подгрузить и выполняет инстанс ппоследнего. для расширения функционала добавляем новый класс расширеный от абстрактного и переписываем метод send.

Comment: @Naumov а есть ли вариант сделать разветвление логики передавая объект класса SMS Network и т.д. и в зависимости от того какому классу принадлежит объект выполнять отправку определенным образом ? или это незачем делать. и как поступить с классом наблюдателем для логов?

Comment: Ответ на первый вопрос дан выше. А второй это примерно так вы в коде классов, выбрасываете какието ивенты послее на каждый ивент берете объект р пишите логирование. Но для логирования как для задачи не стоит использовать обсервер это усложнит логику. Стоит использовать какой либо статический метод, в котором вы сможете обрабатывать состояние логов, файлы или б.д. для их записи. И просто вписывайте и логируйто то что вам надо.

Comment: Если это в рамках PHP, то не стоит морочится и ждать пока будет реализация шаблонов. Достаточно использовать интерфейса, для ваших двух классов: SmsMessage & SocialNetworkMessage.
И не забывайте о MVC, где у Вас пропадет надобность использовать GetDriver если Вы разделити их в разные контролеры.

Comment: @Makarenko_I_V Вы именно про шаблоны прожектирования речь ведёте или про template типа SomeClass < 20, int > SomeVariable? Ведь шаблоны прожектирования ждать не надо. Либо придерживаешься этой практики, либо нет. Т.е. это всегда самостоятельная реализация. Наличие каких-то стандартных заготовок может к этому только подтолкнуть. Но всё всегда можно извратить по-своему.

Comment: @Sergey, про template. "Но всё всегда можно извратить по-своему" - на здоровье. Только не жалуйтесь, что ваша реализация будет лежать на http://govnokod.ru/

Comment: @Makarenko_I_V причем тут говнокод точка ру? Весеннее обострение?

Comment: @Makarenko_I_V, а при чем тут template? В тегах к вопросу стоят метки `design-patterns` и `design`. А значит речь о шаблонах проектирования, к которым относится и тот же MVC.

Comment: Программа как таковая - функциональная, шаблоны в своей сути позволяют структурировать использование этого функционала в общепонятном пути и обобщить там где это возможно.

Comment: Вопрос излизанный до дыр :) Больше и качественнее ответы вы могли получить поискав в инете.http://padabum.com/d.php?id=15070

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Стоит. Только нужно внести ясность.

Обычно полагают, что код пишется "на один раз" или "код слишком простой". На практике часто оказывается, что "да, оно одноразовое, но надо добавить это...и это". В итоге рождается привычка сразу делать структурно - выделить классы, за которыми спрятать лапшу (точек расширения не надо, просто порядок), а в случае веба взять любой фреймворк, а не тешить себя мыслями "да тут делов то ерунда, роутинг простой, шаблоны не надо"

Практически всегда есть смысл разделить на логгеры, манагеры, ридеры, чтобы оперировать более высокими уровнями абстракции и спрятать за ними детали, если вы не пишете админские скрипты или не фрилансите (написал, отдал, забыл)

Главное не забывать, что шаблоны призваны решать общие проблемы общими способами. Поэтому не должно быть "ооп ради ооп" и "шаблоны ради шаблонов". 
Тут многие совершают ошибку - начитаются умных книг и пытаются применить шаблон.

Суть в том, что шаблоны - общие решения, которые как то названы. При решении проблем люди приходят к общим решениям, называют его и пишут в книжку. И шаблоны полезны - знание шаблонов может подсказать приемлемые варианты и мозг приучается видеть их сразу. Впрочем, даже если не знать ни одного, то на практике все равно сам их изобретаешь. Также помогают в коммуникации (назвать шаблон проще, чем пояснять, что за структура классов и как она связана).
Но решать то нужно задачи, потому на задачах и нужно акцентироваться, а не на шаблонах.

Правильный путь такой: берем правило "делай все проще", добавляем в него "главная сила ооп не в 3 китах, а в гибкости объектов и возможности комбинировать их", приправляем приемами чистого кода и других парадигмами - и решаем задачу. Если видим, что подходит какой то шаблон (обычно не понять какой точно, слишком тонкая грань), то идем к нему решая задачу. Как только задача решена, то все - дальше реализовывать шаблон не нужно. Нет причины - нет кода. Неважно насколько решение получилось "классическим" - любое продолжение есть усложнение.

Так что разбираться в шаблонах полезно - это как перенимать чужой опыт решения типичных проблем. И использовать полезно. Но чтобы избежать попадания в ловушку "шаблоны ради шаблонов" следует использовать прием, каким шаблон решает задачу, закодить его и остановиться.

Comment: Вы пишете "подходит какой-то шаблон", но это некорректная формулировка. Шаблоны проектирования - это не образцы, по которым нужно все сделать, а рекомендации к действию. Поэтому шаблоны проектирования не могут подходить или не подходить, - **им можно и нужно следовать**. Следование шаблонам, как правило, даст лучший результат. Более простой, понятный, лаконичный, функциональный, расширяемый...

Comment: @Razzwan да весь мой пост про то, что шаблоны это рекомендации к действию. Потому что шаблонов много и есть родственные, что и сбивает с толку тех, кто пытается именно полностью реализовать выбранный шаблон.

Comment: "или не фрилансите (написал, отдал, забыл)" - не совсем так, на определенном этапе фриланса начинаешь пользоваться своими же наработками из других проектов, особенно если специализируешься на чем-либо одном. Так что в итоге оказывается проще и удобнее писать свои собственные обертки классов, пакеты и тд.

Comment: Есть ли хороший источник где можно почитать про шаблоны? Точнее как называется шаблон, и когда использовать (может с примером). Укажите если не сложно плз.

Comment: @nick_n_a я изучал шаблоны по GoF(слишком академично) и потом книга http://javatutor.net/books/tip (практично и заодно как пример того, что в разных языках одни шаблоны или не нужны или нужно делать проще). ну а дальше куча всего (я давно программирую). Только я никогда не следую шаблонам буквально. Изучение шаблон "форматирует" мозг чтобы тот сразу видел "возможные расширяемые решения" и хороши для коммуникации, но моя цель - решать задачу, а не реализовывать идеальный шаблон

Comment: Спасибо. Один из весёлых вопросов на собеседовании "какие шаблоны проэктирования вы знаете/использовали" может отлично поставить в тупик))) да и на работе все удивились что я это не знаю. это пожалуй для развития. Сам пишу много лет.

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ. Всё очень чётко, у меня похожее понимание шаблонов и методологий программирования, и что на них не надо зацикливаться и всюду пихать.

Answer (score 23):

Вопрос "стоит ли использовать шаблоны" - это всё равно что вопрос "а стоит ли использовать тапочки" - **не имеет однозначного ответа** без конкретики. В твоём случае пример есть, и по примеру: стоит, и это шаблон адаптер. НО, хотелось бы ответить не только по поводу этого случая, а более глобально.

**Шаблоны проектирования не обязательно двигают дизайн в хорошую сторону**. У всего есть обратная сторона. Хороший код должен быть максимально читаем любыми прогерами, и должен быть прост - таковы одни из основных современных тенденций программирования. Шаблоны делают код более гибким - но они его зачастую усложняют. Фабрики - плодят классы, синглтон - рушит инкапсуляцию, деревья - требуют сложную логику для удобной работы с ними, декораторы - сиильно усложняют понимание работы "целого", нарушают SRP, и.т.п.  Есть и фундаментальные паттерны - например стратегия, шаблонный метод, строитель: хочешь не хочешь, а будешь их использовать, если используешь наследование.

Но, **это не значит - что паттерны GoF плохи**. Они позволяют сделать сложную систему простой без излишних умозаключений программиста. Ключевое слово тут - сложную. Если известно ТЗ на конечную систему/подсистему - можно расчитать, насколько она сложная, и если простая - то паттерны лишний раз не пихать, а если сложная - использовать паттерны по максимуму, внося ясность и гибкость. Рассчитать - это как раз обязанность архитектора, или сотрудника, выполняющего его обязанности(лида).

А если ТЗ нет, или ТЗ лишь итерация проекта, или пишете проект на удачу(совершенно не зная что впереди): то следует применять к коду эволюционный подход. Это значит, что пока всё просто и проект только начинается, можно смело забыть про паттерны. Как только появилось узкое место, которое "течёт", в котором сложный код, или не хватает гибкости: рефакторите код, применяете паттерны для упрощения и повышения гибкости. Это соответствует принципу [YAGNI](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/556137/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8-ocp-%D0%B8-dip-%D0%B8%D0%B7-solid-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF-yagni) . Конечно этот принцип не противоречит тому, чтобы взять фреймворк за основу проекта, что уже даст годную архитектуру даже без модификаций: ведь ваш код будет вне кода фреймворка, правда это потребует более "прокачанных" программистов.

У YAGNI также есть одна проблема - зачастую заказчик ставит "срочные задачи", которые просто не дают времени на встраивание паттернов и рефакторинг тогда, когда в них появилась необходимость. Или же программист - у которого нет мотивации впахивать, чтобы сделать суперпроект: просто забивает на то, что заказчик не увидит. Это решается путём обозначения YAGNI-способа развития проекта между заказчиком и исполнителем при старте проекта.

Так что вердикт - паттерны это очень полезно, но очень очень плохо - когда их лепят не к месту. Семь раз отмерь, один раз отрежь. Надеюсь археология вопроса была полезна.

P.S. Этот вопрос ломал мне голову от первых потугов работы программистом: все статьи пестрили слоганами "используй паттерны", "паттерны - добро", "не знаешь паттерны - сам виноват". А всё оказалось не столь однозначно, почему то об обратной стороне медали мало писали в статьях про паттерны, и наивные программисты вроде меня бросались всё делать через них..

Answer (score 16):

**Шаблоны использовать, однозначно, стОит.**

Напишу сначала общие мысли, а потом применительно к вашей конкретной задаче.

**Общие мысли:**
Все шаблоны проектирования - это микс лучших решений, простейших решений, наиболее понятных решений, наименее трудозатратных решений. Это опыт поколений, который нам оставили предыдущие разработчики.

Шаблоны проектирования - это автомобиль с бензиновым двигателем вместо осла, это телега на колесах вместо мешков на спине, это ракета в космос вместо слонов на черепахе.

Шаблоны проектирования - это решение тех проблем, которые у вас пока еще не возникли, но обязательно возникнут, если вы не будете им следовать.

Шаблоны проектирования - это короткие выводы из многотысячестраничной макулатуры, это естественный отбор наиболее приспособленных к жизни решений, это простые истины, которые всем известны, но не все сумели подобрать для них слова. Это хорошо, просто, быстро и эффективно.

**Теперь применительно к вашей конкретной задаче:**
Вы пишете:

> Стоит ли заморачиваться с шаблонами? Может следует сделать это отдельными классами все?

Вы противопоставляете шаблоны проектирования отдельным классам для реализации того или иного механизма, но это неверно. Ведь у вас в любом случае будет отдельный класс для работы с `SMS`, отдельный для 
`socialNetwork`, в идеале, для каждой социальной сети будет отдельный класс. Именно они, эти классы, должны передаваться в качестве аргумента в ваш метод `GetDriver`. И они должны реализовывать один и тот же интерфейс.

Такая схема одновременно будет соответствовать всем шаблонам проектирования и будет более простой в реализации. Почему более простой? Потому что мозгу всегда просто цепляться за что-то конкретное, стандартное и понятное, чем реализовывать каждый раз одни и те же идеи разными способами.

**Вместо выводов:**
Если вы вдруг решили просто мне поверить на слово - зря. Сомневайтесь! Шаблоны тоже неидеальны. Вы - новое поколение, которое сделает новые открытия. Попытайтесь сформулировать, что в существующих шаблонах не так. Если вам это удастся - мы прочтем вашу книгу ;)

Answer (score 15):

Применять шаблоны проектирования определённо стоит.

За время существования ООП был накоплен довольно большой опыт. Позднее этот опыт был структурирован и обобщён для родственных между собой задач. Собственно так и появились шаблоны.

Пытаясь решить задачу "своим способом" велика вероятность изобрести очередной "велосипед", который, к тому же, ещё не факт, что будет эффективно работать.

В тоже время, важно понимать, что шаблон лишь обобщённый способ решения определённых задач. Поэтому нужно подбирать шаблон для конкретной задачи, не наоборот подгонять задачу под конкретный шаблон.

В противном случае, пытаясь улучшить реализацию с помощью шаблонов вполне вероятно вместо пользы нанести серьёзный вред.

Разбираясь в шаблонах Вы не только перенимаете полезный опыт. Анализ шаблонов способствует более глубокому пониманию ООП и архитектуры ПО.
Только, повторюсь, чтобы достигнуть положительного эффекта нужно использовать шаблоны правильно и там где это действительно нужно, а не реализовывать шаблоны просто ради них самих.

Comment: Шаблоны действительно стоит использовать, но только если это необходимо с точки зрения архитектуры проекта - на то они и шаблоны что форсируют определённые методы использования - ради полезности или нет уже определяется "на месте". Их использование ради только того чтобы иметь их бессмысленно, так же как и с точки зрения бизнеса менять среду разработки только ради того что вышла новая версия. Необходимо сначала понять для чего это нужно, какая будет выгода и затраты на поддержку, разработку и издержки.

Answer (score 2):

Касательно примера в оп-посте, возможно вам стоит ознакомиться с более общими принципами ООП, такими, как SOLID.

В вашем случае, согласно принципе Open-Closed, ваши CommunicationDriver'ы следует отнаследовать от CommunicationDriverAbstract:

```
abstract class CommunicationDriverAbstract 
{
    public function setMsg($msg) {
        ...
    }

    abstract function setRecipient($recipient);
}
```

Comment: Вы специально отметили ответ как "общий"? За плюсы на таких ответах вы не получите репутации, т.к. "общие" ответы считаются принадлежащими community, а не конкретному автору.

Comment: @PashaPash, специально, я просто хотел посмотреть, как это работает и надеялся, что кто-то сможет улучшить ответ

Answer (score -1):

Шаблоны проектирования - это метод увеличения повторного иcпользования кода.
Сейчас от них никуда ни денешься, они везде.
Время затраченное на их изучение окупается с лихвой, особенно для типовых задач.
Хотя проектирование строго сверху-вниз дает более оптимальные решения, оно значительно дороже.

Попробуйте придумать новый алгоритм или математическую формулу, и вы поймете.

Comment: Правда в глаза колит?