# Паттерны проектирования

Tags: java, ооп, шаблоны-проектирования

Изучаю Java, почитал о паттернах проектирования на Хабрахабре и других источниках, посмотрел видео в ютубе (не очень как оказалось).

Что такое паттерны? Какие они бывают? Зачем они нужны и т.д.?

Comment: Слишком широкий вопрос - вам в статейники. Тут вы тоже сможете некоторое интересное прочесть - читайте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/510342/ и связанные вопросы.

Comment: Паттерны - набор стандартных решений для типичных задач. Многие паттерны очень похожи между собой. Причина именно в том, что паттерн идет от задачи к решению и, если решение одно и тоже, то это значит, что это решение хорошее, но, поскольку задачи разные, то и паттерны разные. То, что вам написали ниже, это GOF-паттерны. Когда говорят паттерны, то обычно подразумевают именно эти. Но вы также должны знать о существовании GRASP-паттернов. Хотя они называются паттернами, но это скорее принципы. Помните, что это лишь шаблон, многие из них в каноническом виде не используются вообще.

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 3):

*Паттерны проектирования* - готовые решения в области программирования (проще говоря, шаблоны). Дабы не "изобретать велосипед", можно воспользоваться готовыми функциями.


[image: Виды]




[image: Все паттерны]



Источник и полное описание: https://habrahabr.ru/post/210288/.

Answer (score 0):

Вот отличный сайт с описанием и примерами всех паттернов. Пускай вас не пугает что они для PHP. Для Java и PHP они одинаковые. Это принцип.
[DesignPatterns](http://designpatternsphp.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/README.html)